# How to configure log4perl.conf and a perl script so as to set correct permissions to log files?

Tags: perl, logging, cpan, log4perl

I am using `Log::Log4Perl` for logging for my perl scripts. Everything is working great, except one thing; I have some common modules used by different scripts (and run by different users). I want those log files to have `-rw-rw-rw-` permissions, but the following code which I am using all over doesn't seem to help:

In my `/etc/log4perl.conf`

```
# Logger for /usr/local/bin/script.pl
log4perl.logger.SCRIPT=DEBUG, SCRIPT_LOG

log4perl.appender.SCRIPT_LOG           = Log::Dispatch::FileRotate
log4perl.appender.SCRIPT_LOG.filename  = /var/log/perl/script.log
log4perl.appender.SCRIPT_LOG.mode      = append
log4perl.appender.SCRIPT_LOG.autoflush = 1
log4perl.appender.SCRIPT_LOG.size      = 2097152
log4perl.appender.SCRIPT_LOG.max       = 5
log4perl.appender.SCRIPT_LOG.layout    = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
```

In my perl script `script.pl`

```
use Log::Log4perl qw(get_logger :levels);

sub _log4perl {

   umask 0000;
   Log::Log4perl->init("/etc/log4perl.conf");
   my $log4perl = get_logger("SCRIPT");    

   return $log4perl;
}
```

This configuration and corresponding code create file `script.log` with permission `-rw-r--r--`, but I want `-rw-rw-rw-`. Is there anything terribly wrong with the code? Please also read [Can file appenders create files with different permissions?](http://log4perl.sourceforge.net/releases/Log-Log4perl/docs/html/Log/Log4perl/FAQ.html#ae9c0)

Comment: Do you have permission to change umask? is umask get set?

Answer (score 1):

You could set permission: [http://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Dispatch::File](http://metacpan.org/pod/Log%3a%3aDispatch%3a%3aFile)

```
log4perl.appender.SCRIPT_LOG.permission = 0644
```

> permissions ($)
>
> If the file does not already exist, the permissions that it should be
>   created with. Optional. The argument passed must be a valid octal
>   value, such as 0600 or the constants available from Fcntl, like
>   S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR.
>
> See "chmod" in perlfunc for more on potential traps when passing octal
>   values around.